# Unable to access HTTP PUT data in webservice code

Tags: php, web-services, rest

All,

As part of an application I'm writing I need to have a HTTP PUT webservice which accepts incoming imagedata, which will by analyzed, validated, and added to a local file store.

My issue arises after the size validation as the

> `$_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']`

has a > 0 value, and this value is identical to the test file size, so I can assume that all is going well up to this point *but* when I try to read the incoming stream data using

> `file_get_contents('php://stdin');`

I get an empty string. I've also tried using

> `file_get_contents('php://input');`

And this give me the same result of an empty string.

Any help, suggestions or direction will be appreciated.

NB: I'm using

- PHP 5.2.6
- Apache 2.0

Comment: Is the script running on IIS or Apache?

Comment: Hey Kev, service is running on apache 2.0. Question text updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that you need to alter httpd.conf to not deny PUT requests. Have you checked that?

Answer (score 2):

Apache HTTPD denies PUT requests by default. You might check out mod_put:
http://perso.ec-lyon.fr/lyonel.vincent/apache/mod_put.html

and add this to httpd.conf:

```
<Location /upload/dir>
  EnablePut On
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Web publishing"
  AuthUserFile /www/etc/passwd
  AuthGroupFile /www/etc/group
  <Limit PUT>
    require valid-user
  </Limit>
</Location>
```

Comment: Turns out that a server configuration revert did the trick, and a PUT disable may have been part of the change.

Thanks so much everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The `r` you've got as the second arg isn't right.  `file_get_contents` doesn't use the `a/r/w/a+/r+/w+` arguments that `fopen` uses.  You probably want to remove it and just do:

```
file_get_contents('php://input');
```

See https://www.php.net/file_get_contents.

Comment: Good point! :) I removed the 'r' from the question code to remove any further confusion. Yet the 'r' is effectively ignored by the file_get_contents, so this doesn't solve the issue of the empty string. (confirmed by changing the app code)

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_contents` doesn't take the "r" parameter - see [the PHP manual page](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents):

```
string file_get_contents  ( string $filename  [, int $flags...)
```

Valid `$flag` values are `FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH, FILE_TEXT, FILE_BINARY`.

Try removing the "r" flag and trying again

**Edit** - question updated, "r" flag was being ignored so evidently not the root of the problem.

It looks like there's a [reported bug in PHP](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=33359) regarding `file_get_contents` returning an empty string for a HTTP POST. From the bug description:

> `file_get_contents('php://input')` (and also `file, fopen+fread`) does not
> return POST data, when submited form with
> enctype="multipart/form-data".

> When submited the same form without enctype specified (so default
> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" is used) all works OK.

So it looks like a work-around is to change the specified form enctype away from `multipart/form-data`, which obviously isn't ideal for an image upload - from the [W3 FORM specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html):

> The content type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" is inefficient for sending large quantities of binary data or text containing non-ASCII characters. The content type "multipart/form-data" should be used for submitting forms that contain files, non-ASCII data, and binary data.

**Further Edit**

This bug seems to have been resolved in your PHP version. Have you checked to make sure that the buffer being read in doesn't start with a carriage-return / newline char? There's a problem somewhat similar to yours that was discussed [on Sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?t=555002).

Try running [`strlen`](https://www.php.net/strlen) on the input and see what the length is.

Comment: I've updated the question code accordingly, but please see my comment on 'dirtslide's response. still empty strings

Comment: Answer updated now, cheers - seems to be a PHP bug in file operations on a POST request and php://input

Comment: This is a curly one! :) That bug is old, and I've confirmed that it's fixed by changing the request method to POST, and it's working fine. My problem is _only_ with the PUT method.

Comment: Hmm, a dilly of a pickle alright! file_get_contents returns false if the stream isn't found, so it's hooking up ok, but not reading any data. Very strange! :)

Comment: I tried the your suggestion about using `strlen`, but I get a `int(0)` when I `var_dump` it's return. I'm going to request a roll back of a change that occurred on the server sometime ago in an effort to get eliminate this from the equation.

Comment: I believe `int(0)` is telling you the string is null-length, so it may be that file_get_contents is seeing an end-of-stream marker right at the start of the uploaded data. Keep us updated after the rollback, this is a very interesting problem that will surely come up for others doing similar stuff